# How can I prevent jquery from selecting a parent when I click on one of the children in that parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

ok quick scenario:

html:

`<span class="answer">blah<input type="radio" value="1"></span>`

jquery:

`$("span.answer").click(

 function() {

check = $("input", this);

check.attr('checked', check.attr('checked') === true ? false : true);

);`

Ok so this will check/uncheck the child radio input inside the selected span when I click inside it.

The problem I have is that I don't want to run this event when I actually click on the radio button itself (obviously because jquery will see the radio button as checked and uncheck - in effect the exact opposite of what should happen usually). Something along the lines of this:

`$("span.answer:not(span input)").click`

This of course doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Leo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a specific html tag to accomplish what you try to do with jquery and javascript ..
it is the [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) tag

```
<label>blah<input type="radio" value="1" /></label>
```

this will have the effect you want

***[update]***
For Internet Explorer 6 to play nice use the complete syntax of the label by using the `for` attribute which targets the id of an form input/select/etc.. element..

```
<label for="radio_1">blah<input id="radio_1" type="radio" value="1" /></label>
```

Comment: Yep this method will work (without javascript) but doesn't play ball in ie6.

Comment: wasn't aware of this .. you can use the `for` attribute to make this work.. look at updated answer..

Comment: Yes that certainly works thank you. I didn't want to use ids for these particular radio inputs but I guess I can work it differently. Any ideas about the broader jquery selector problem detailed below?

Comment: @Leo, You should use the code of Koobz for that, but for a more generic approach you could change it to `$('.answer').click( function(){/*your normal code here*/} ).children().click( function(evt){evt.stopPropagation();})`. This might become overkill, though, in situations where your `.answer` element has lots of children (*1st level*)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the very quick replies (and to Koobz et al).

Answer (score 5):

```
$("span.answer input").click(function(evt)
{
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Will prevent the click event from bubbling up (and triggering the handler on "span.answer".)

Comment: Yeah this definitely works as I need it to. Is this the most elegant solution to the problem do you think?  

There are many occasions where I have an event bound to element which I don't want to trigger when I click on a child of that element. I thought there might be some fancy selector technique to accomplish this along the lines of the example in my question.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original question, however, using the <label for...> tag is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Yes, in this case, correct use of the `label` tag automatically results in the behavior you're looking for without javascript. 

Otherwise, there's no selector to accomplish what you're looking for. If you click on a child element, it bubbles up. It's the way thing work and it's usually desirable.